# Refresh page after and call a function automatically in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a function that refreshes the page and then call element and click:

```
const handlePDF = () => {
    
    window.location.reload(false); 
   
    pdfRef.current.click()

  };
```

I had thought about setTimeout but it doesn't work like that either.

I imagine that I have to save that order in memory once the page is refreshed but I don't know how to do it.

I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` on window load event to solve that.

**1. Listen window on load**

```
window.onload = () => {
    let reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        pdfRef.current.click();
    }
}
```

**2. Save a `session` on `handlePDF` call**

```
const handlePDF = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
    window.location.reload(false); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks @RyanLe. I learn a lot from your answers on SO

Comment: Thank you very much Danial has worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to your's, before.

The solution that I settled with is to use `sessionStorage` to flag states, so that some flag is available to you, upon page refresh.

Then, you'd look for that flag in a `useEffect` callback.

But first, let's create a constant, so that we don't aimlessly repeat ourselves.

```
const handlePdfFlag = 'handle_pdf';
```

Then, create the flag in localStorage, then reload the page.

```
const handlePDF = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem(handlePdfFlag, 'true');
  window.location.reload(false);
};
```

Then, in some `useEffect`, you'd pick up the flag, ensuring that you delete the flag afterwards.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(handlePdfFlag) === 'true' && pdfRef.current) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(handlePdfFlag);
    pdfRef.current.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, I have used the version of windows.onload but maybe it is better to use useEffect, I would have to take a closer look!

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using react.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that does some code based on something changing then maybe the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook will work for you.